# SQL query to select rows having 2 columns equal value

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id    || name  || published
--------------------------
1     || john  || 1
7     || alex  || 0
1     || roco  || 0
4     || mika  || 0
16    || mika  || 1
8     || zack  || 1
8     || alfi  || 1
```

Which sql query should I run to return IDs 16 and 8?

I tried the following but I'm always having IDs 1, 16 and 8:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, published
            FROM table
            WHERE published > 0
            GROUP BY id) B
ON A.id = B.id AND A.published = B.published
GROUP BY id
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why 16 and 8? Which logic leads to 16 and 8?

Comment: GROUP BY id HAVING MIN(published) > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Group By` with conditional aggregation in `Having` clause to consider only those where **published** has **never been** zero.

```
SELECT id
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM(published = 0) = 0
```

Alternatively, as *@Gordon Linoff* [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855800/sql-query-to-select-rows-having-2-columns-equal-value/52855990#comment92628437_52855990), you can use the following as well:

```
SELECT id
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING MIN(published) > 0
```

Comment: @wdotis happy to help :)

Comment: I would use `min(published)  > 0`, but it is the same thing in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You seems want `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table a1 WHERE a1.id = a.id AND a1.published = 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `not in`

```
select t.* from your_table t
where t.id not in (
                  select id from your_table t1
                  where t1.published=0
                 )
```

output

```
id  name    published
16  mika    1
8   alif    1
8   zack    1
```

[DEMO DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24afed5c62d7f90b8760550e5dced462)

Comment: You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieved using

```
SELECT name, published
FROM A
WHERE id IN (16, 8)
ORDER BY id;
```